# get days between two chosen days using DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datetimepicker

I am using two dateTimePicker's, and lets say I've chosen 11-11-2011 on the first, and 17-11-2011 on the last. Now I want to get the dates between these two dates. I just want to get a result like this:

```
11-11-2011 
12-11-2011 
13-11-2011 
14-11-2011 
15-11-2011 
16-11-2011 
17-11-2011
```

How am I supposed to do this ?

I've tried to make it out from the question by James Hill, but couldnt figure it out. 
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Today;
DateTime end = DateTime.Today.AddDays(7);

for (DateTime current = start; current <= end; current = current.AddDays(1))
{
    Console.WriteLine(current);
}
```

I like using a for-loop for this kind of stuff, since I do often miss them in modern .NET projects :)

A possible helper method:

```
static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetRange(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    for (DateTime current = start; current <= end; current = current.AddDays(1))
    {
        yield return current;
    }
}
```

**Important** If you have a time-portion as well, the condition must be changed to `current.Date <= end.Date`

**Edit** Changed so that the boundaries are included, I previously only provided the dates in-between.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work too:

```
var timeSpan = (last.Value - first.Value);

var result = new List<DateTime>()
for (int i = 0; i < timeSpan.Days; i++)
{
    a.Add (first.AddDays (i));
}
return result;
```